# Aurelia tutorial collapsible navbar not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, aurelia

I'm following the [Aurelia tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/getting-started/5) and I've noticed that the bootstrap collapsible navbar isn't working at all. I've found someone's [heroku app](http://aurelia-dialog-sample.herokuapp.com/) online with the exact same problem.

Here's my source

```
<template>
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
<require from="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"></require>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <span>${router.title}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="loader" if.bind="router.isNavigating">
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="page-host">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Any idea as to what is going on with this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're including the bootstrap library in your application.

**app.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min'; // or wherever it is
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'index.html' add this line: 
<--JSPM Has a Bug with Bootstrap so We Have to Include jQuery Here-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
I think that's all you need, if it don't work let me know. Good luck.